# Spring Data JPA SortOrder Requires Database Column Name Rather than Attribute Name

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Given an Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(schema = "THESCHEMA", name = "USER")
public class User extends RepresentationModel<User> {
// ...
    @Column(name = "USER_LNAME")
    private String lastName;
    
// ...
}
```

and a Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao dao;
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/users")
    public PagedModel<User> getUsers(
    // ...
    @SortDefault(sort = "USER_LNAME") @PageableDefault(size = PageDefaults.PAGE_SIZE) final Pageable pageable) {
        Page<User> page = dao.findAll(pageable);
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

and Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String> {
    // ...
    public Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

works as long as @SortDefault sort= the name of a database table. As this will be passed in
http://localhost:8080/my-app/users?sort=user_lname we don't want to expose the column name.

We would much rather use the attribute that is mapped in the Entity.
http://localhost:8080/my-app/users?sort=lastName

Is there a way to configure this to take the mapped attribute or to (easily) get the column_name from the attribute name?